# SPOnline no longer search hits on contentclass

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results

All of a sudden, from yesterday to today, I lost the capability to search for contentclass:sts_site or sts_web content throughout the site collections we have. Other contentclasses in those sites will show up, so no difference there. There has been no changes made, from yesterday to today. The closest description of my problem I've found is 
[Publishing sites, search and the missing contentclass:STS_Site & STS_Web](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1744/publishing-sites-search-and-the-missing-contentclasssts-site-sts-web)

ideas, anyone?

Comment: Not posting this as an answer, but these queries work on my sites in O365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the symptom is a result of MS having farm wide problems related to the search service. Will see in a day or two if they have managed to resolve this and gotten the search back to full functionality.